# Preference screen xml

Tags: android

I have a main view that presents to the user the settings he/she can modify for an application . It's xml is something like this :

```
<PreferenceScreen  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"          
   android:key="root_preferencescreen">

    <PreferenceScreen  android:key="general_sett" android:title="general settings" />
     ....

    <PreferenceScreen  android:key="extras_sett" android:title="extras settings" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

When the user clicks on on preferenceScreen a secondary screen will open that contains the desired preferences . What I want is to be able to display a icon to the left of each of these preferenceScreens , something like this:

```
<PreferenceScreen  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"          
       android:key="root_preferencescreen">

  <LinearLayout  android:orientation="horizontal"  android:layout_width="fill_parent"... >

        <ImageView id="@+id/picview" ... />

        <PreferenceScreen  android:key="general_sett" android:title="general settings" />

  </LinearLayout>
    ......

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Unfortunately this approach is not allowed by Android , so if you have any other idea or solution regarding this issue please inform me .

Comment: What are you seeing that leads you to believe that Android does not allow your proposed approach? I just tried it myself and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [`android:widgetLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#attr_android:widgetLayout) property in the `Preference` Javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it can't be done easily on a `PreferenceScreen`, but it's real easy on a `Preference`

xml:

```
    <Preference
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:key="key"
        android:summary="@string/text"
        android:title="@string/title" />
```

in your `PreferenceActivity`:

```
    Preference other = (Preference) findPreference("key");
    other.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
             // start a new PreferenceActivity
             Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), second_pref_screen.class); 
             startActivity(i);
             return true;
         }
    });
```